# Can I have an empty Java class?

Tags: java, class, abstract

I'm creating a grid based game.

I need to implement a set of obstacles that take random positions within the grid.
I've created an abstract class `ALifeForm`, that holds the common methods for every item within the grid. Obviously, abstract classes can't be initialised, so I was going to create a new class `AObstacle`, which will extend `ALifeForm`.

Only issue is, my `AObstacle` class isn't specialised. All the methods it needs are within `ALifeForm`.

Can I have an empty class? 
Is it bad programming practice? And if so, what can I implement instead?

Comment: "Can I have an empty Java class?" - Yes.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Then why `ALifeForm` is `abstract`, since it's subclasses don't provide anything?

Comment: Have you considered change your class from abstract  to concrete? If one subclass can be an exactly copy but with another name, then it may be the case that the superclass should be instantiable.

Comment: If it fits the way you are modelling the entities in your game, have an empty class. It's fine.

Comment: Instead of an empty `abstract` class, you could consider an `interface`

Comment: @BrunoMarcoVisioli: That may work structurally, but I suspect it would cause more problems semantically.  That would mean that all child classes are now instances of this concrete base... *thing*.  It's likely that this inheritance model isn't the right way to go in the first place.  But it's very rare that the solution is to just instantiate the base class.  While it may *structurally* work, it introduces weird semantics to the domain.

Answer (score 11):

Of course...

```
class AObstacle { }
```

(Plus whatever inheritance model you're using.)  There's nothing stopping you from doing this.

Remember that a *class* isn't really a thing that you're defining.  A *type* is.  The class is just the language/syntax construct used to describe the type.  If the type being described has no attributes or operations aside from the inheritance model, then there's nothing else to add to it.

Though you *are* adding one thing.  You're giving it a name.  It doesn't sound like much, but defining a semantic concept with a concrete name (particularly in a statically typed environment) is *very* important.  Your type now has an identity apart from other types in the system.  If things are added to it later, there's a place to add them without refactorings and breaking changes.

Comment: And though empty classes that inherit from an abstract class are probably a code smell, sometimes they are the best way to describe the structures you want to model. Judging by the description of the scenario in the question, this seems to be such a case with one slight caveat: is an obstacle really a life form? Maybe `ALifeForm` should be renamed as `AGridItem` or something similar that encompasses both living things and inanimate obstacles.

Comment: @biziclop: Very true.  We don't really know enough about the domain being modeled to be certain.  This could be a violation of Liskov Substitution as a design consideration, entirely separate from whether or not the language supports empty classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well to do it you don't need to have an abstract class and a class that extends it, or an empty class(*wich is possible too*).

**First way:**

You just need to implement two classes: The class that contains the methods and the variables you need to use and the second calss that has an instance of your first class:

```
public class A{
  public void firstMethod(){
    //do your stuff here
  }
....
}

public class B{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   A a=new A(); //instantiate your class here 
   a.firstMethod();// then just use its methods
  }
}
```

> Because if you implement a class that extends an abstract class it should implement all its methods.

**Second way:**

- Or if you want your second class to be specialized you could have :

your first class wich should not be abstract and the second one can extend it and use all its methods, and have its specific methods

Comment: While this is technically correct, it isn't always good practice.

Comment: @biziclop Yes are right, but it's just a way of doing it, and seriously I can't figure out what's the purpose of all of this !!