# Do we ever need empty class in java project? If yes then why?

Tags: java, project, empty-class

In empty class (without field and properties) also compiler automatically creates a default constructor after compiling. If we never use this empty class then why compiler creates this default constructor?

Comment: Maybe for some custom exception, for the "why the compiler" => because of the JLS, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor

Comment: A marker interface, like [`RandomAccess`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html), is like this, although I don't think that's exactly what you had in mind since it's not a class per se and doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: About empty classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28090223/can-i-have-an-empty-java-class

Comment: Besides being mandated by the Java Language Specification: The compiler does not know whether you use this empty class or not - the class could be defined (and compiled) in project A and a subclass of it in a different project B

Comment: it must not be a subclass in a different project, it may just instanciated in a second project

Answer (score 1):

We can use it as type token e.g:

```
class DatabaseColumnName {}
class DatabaseTableName {}
addItem(DatabaseColumnName.class, "Age")
addItem(DatabaseTableName.class, "Person")
...
getItemsByType(DatabaseTableName.class)
```

Also, read about usages in other languages to have deeper understanding of empty classes:

Kotlin: [What is the purpose of empty class in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588670/what-is-the-purpose-of-empty-class-in-kotlin/47595189#47595189)

C#: [Advantages of an empty class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035180/advantages-of-an-empty-class-in-c)