# Kotlin classes without curly braces

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I have noticed that we can create classes in Kotlin without curly braces like below.

```
//Example classFile.kt
class Empty

class SecondEmpty

fun firstMethod() {

}
```

My question is, why we need such feature? in which situation we can use this?

In the above example, I have written a method called `firstMethod()` how can I call that from the other objects?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588670/what-is-the-purpose-of-empty-class-in-kotlin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of empty class in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588670/what-is-the-purpose-of-empty-class-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 2):

Empty classes have been discussed in [What is the purpose of empty class in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588670/what-is-the-purpose-of-empty-class-in-kotlin) already.

Regarding your `firstMethod`: in Kotlin, we have so called top-level functions. These can be defined in any file without an enclosing class. Another example for this is `main` which is defined top-level in most cases.

**How to call top-level functions?**

You can simply import the function into other files and call them. For instance, if `firstMethod` were defined in `com/x/Example.kt` (package com.x), you may import `com.x.firstMethod` in other Kotlin files and call that method.

For Java, it’s important to know, that top-level functions are compiled into a class as `static` members. As for the example above, you can call `com.x.ExampleKt.firstMethod` from Java.

Comment: How can you find out that `firstMethod` is declared inside `Example.kt` file?