# Kotlin - What is the use of class without body?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

In Kotlin both the header and the body are optional; if the class has no body, curly braces can be omitted.

So we can define class like,

```
class Empty
```

What is the use of this type of class?

Comment: The same as a `public class Empty { }` in Java?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use it for some custom exceptions:

```
class Empty : Exception()
```

or as a [marker interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern):

```
interface Empty
```

or as a [data class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html):

```
data class Empty(val s: String)
```

or as a [marker annotation](https://codescracker.com/java/java-marker-annotations.htm):

```
annotation class Empty
```

~ *That's a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090353/7637657) to read.*

Comment: And, `data class MyDataClass(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin allows to declare any type without body, for example:

```
interface Interface;

class Class;

annotation class Annotation;

sealed class SealedClass;

data class DataClass(var value: String);

object ObjectClass;

enum class EnumClass;

class CompanionClass {
    companion object
}
```

the usage of each definition can be described as below:

- interface - as a [marker interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850328/marker-interfaces-in-java).
- annotation - describe the annotated type has some ability. e.g: junit4 `@Before` and `@After` annotations.
- object - it often present as a token or a lock or a placeholder and .etc. e.g: `synchronized(lock){ /*thread safe working*/ }`
- data class - quickly define a java [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) class with `getters`, `setters`? , `equals`, `hashCode`, `toString` and `componentN` operators for destructuring in kotlin.
- others - they are meaningless, just are the language syntax.